# C# App.Config - Not getting values for courses collection

Tags: c#

I am attempting to read values from my config file into my program. I'm trying an example that I found online at http://www.bardev.com/2013/11/17/kickstart-c-custom-configuration/.

I've set up the config and the classes the same way that I see it on the site. I can get the values for school name, address, city and state but I'm unable to get back the Settings.Courses values and also getting the following errors when running the code as is:

**Exception Unhandled**

> 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in SchoolBlog.exe. Additional information: The type initializer for 'SchoolBlog.SchoolConfig' threw an exception.

**Inner Exception** (key part of problem)

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element 'courses'.

**Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="school" type="SchoolBlog.SchoolConfig, SchoolBlog" />
  </configSections>

  <school name="Manchester High">
    <address street="123 Main Street" city="Mandeville" state="Manchester"/>
    <courses>
      <course title="Math"></course>
      <course title="English" instructor="Thompson"></course>
    </courses>
  </school>            
</configuration>
```

**Classes**

```
public class SchoolConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
   private static SchoolConfig _schoolConfig = (SchoolConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("school");
   public static SchoolConfig Settings { get { return _schoolConfig; } }


   [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
   public string Name { get { return (string)base["name"]; } }


   [ConfigurationProperty("address")]
   public AddressElement Address { get { return (AddressElement)base["address"]; } }
}

public class AddressElement : ConfigurationElement
{
   [ConfigurationProperty("street")]
   public string Street { get { return (string)base["street"]; } }

   [ConfigurationProperty("city")]
   public string City { get { return (string)base["city"]; } }

   [ConfigurationProperty("state")]
   public string State { get { return (string)base["state"]; } }
}

public class CourseElement : ConfigurationElement
{
   [ConfigurationProperty("title", IsRequired = true)]
   public string Title { get { return (string)base["title"]; } }

   [ConfigurationProperty("instructor", IsRequired = false)]
   public string Instructor { get { return (string)base["instructor"]; } }

   [ConfigurationProperty("courses")]
   public CourseElementCollection Courses { get { return (CourseElementCollection)base["courses"]; } }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(CourseElement), AddItemName = "course", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
public class CourseElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
   public ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
   { get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap; } }

   protected override string ElementName
   {
      get
      {
         //return base.ElementName;
         return "course";
      }
   }

   protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
   {
      return new CourseElement();
   }

   protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
   {
      return (element as CourseElement).Title;
   }

   public CourseElement this[int index]
   {
      get { return (CourseElement)base.BaseGet(index); }
      set
      {
         if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
         {
            base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
         }
         base.BaseAdd(index, value);
      }
   }

   public CourseElement this[string title]
   { get { return (CourseElement)base.BaseGet(title); } }
}
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

   //int coursesCount = SchoolConfig.Settings;
   string schoolName = SchoolConfig.Settings.Name;
   string schoolStreet = SchoolConfig.Settings.Address.Street;
   string schoolCity = SchoolConfig.Settings.Address.City;
   string schoolState = SchoolConfig.Settings.Address.State;

   Console.WriteLine("School Name: {0} ", schoolName);
   Console.WriteLine("School Address: {0} {1} {2} ", schoolStreet, schoolCity, schoolState);
   //Console.WriteLine("Course Count: {0} ", coursesCount);

   Console.WriteLine("\r\nDone");
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The `CourseElement` class inherits from `ConfigurationElement`. The `CouseElement` class is very similar to the other Element classes that we created earlier. Even though I will not go into detail about the `CourseElement` class, do note that the `IsRequired` property for each `ConfigurationProperty` attribute. One is set to true and the other is set to false.

Comment: You don't have a courses element collection property in the SchoolConfig class.

Comment: Its right there in the CourseElement class

Comment: yes but where is it in the `SchoolConfig` class? `SchoolConfig` doesn't know about `courses` so how will it be able to load it? All you are loading at the moment is the `Name` property and `address`.

Comment: you need to move `[ConfigurationProperty("courses")]
   public CourseElementCollection Courses { get { return (CourseElementCollection)base["courses"]; } }` into `SchoolConfig` I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class for `SchoolConfig` is missing a property for `Courses`. Update the class to the following and it should work.

```
public class SchoolConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    public static SchoolConfig Settings { get; } = (SchoolConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("school");

    [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get { return (string)base["name"]; } }

    [ConfigurationProperty("address")]
    public AddressElement Address { get { return (AddressElement)base["address"]; } }

    [ConfigurationProperty("courses")]
    public CourseElementCollection Courses { get { return base["courses"] as CourseElementCollection; } }
}
```